# Lua: Working with Bit32 Library to Change States of I/O's

Tags: io, lua, bit-manipulation, modbus

I am trying to understand exactly how programming in Lua can change the state of I/O's with a Modbus I/O module.  I have read the modbus protocol and understand the registers, coils, and how a read/write string should look.  But right now, I am trying to grasp how I can manipulate the read/write bit(s) and how functions can perform these actions.  I know I may be very vague right now, but hopefully the following functions, along with some questions throughout them, will help me better convey where I am having the disconnect.  It has been a very long time since I've first learned about bit/byte manipulation.

```
local funcCodes = { --[[I understand this part]]
    readCoil = 1, 
    readInput = 2,
    readHoldingReg = 3,
    readInputReg = 4,
    writeCoil = 5,
    presetSingleReg = 6,
    writeMultipleCoils = 15,
    presetMultipleReg = 16
}
local function toTwoByte(value)
    return string.char(value / 255, value % 255) --[[why do both of these to the same value??]]
end
local function readInputs(s)
    local s = mperia.net.connect(host, port)
    s:set_timeout(0.1)
    local req = string.char(0,0,0,0,0,6,unitId,2,0,0,0,6)
    local req = toTwoByte(0) .. toTwoByte(0) .. toTwoByte(6) ..
    string.char(unitId, funcCodes.readInput)..toTwoByte(0) ..toTwoByte(8)
    s:write(req)
    local res = s:read(10)
    s:close()
    if res:byte(10) then
        local out = {}
        for i = 1,8 do
            local statusBit = bit32.rshift(res:byte(10), i - 1) --[[What is bit32.rshift actually doing to the string?  and the same is true for the next line with bit32.band.
            out[#out + 1] = bit32.band(statusBit, 1)
        end
        for i = 1,5 do
            tDT.value["return_low"] = tostring(out[1])
            tDT.value["return_high"] = tostring(out[2])
            tDT.value["sensor1_on"] = tostring(out[3])
            tDT.value["sensor2_on"] = tostring(out[4])
            tDT.value["sensor3_on"] = tostring(out[5])
            tDT.value["sensor4_on"] = tostring(out[6])
            tDT.value["sensor5_on"] = tostring(out[7])
            tDT.value[""] = tostring(out[8])
            end
        end
        return tDT
    end
```

If I need to be a more specific with my questions, I'll certainly try.  But right now I'm having a hard time connecting the dots with what is actually going on to the bit/byte manipulation here.  I've read both books on the bit32 library and sources online, but still don't know what these are really doing.  I hope that with these examples, I can get some clarification.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
--[[why do both of these to the same value??]]
```

There are two different values here: value / 255 and value % 255. The "/" operator represents divison, and the "%" operator represents (basically) taking the remainder of division.

Before proceeding, I'm going to point out that 255 here should almost certainly be 256, so let's make that correction before proceeding. The reason for this correction should become clear soon.

Let's look at an example.

```
value = 1000
print(value / 256) -- 3.90625
print(value % 256) -- 232
```

Whoops! There was another problem. string.char wants integers (in the range of 0 to 255 -- which has 256 distinct values counting 0), and we may be given it a non-integer. Let's fix that problem:

```
value = 1000
print(math.floor(value / 256)) -- 3
-- in Lua 5.3, you could also use value // 256 to mean the same thing
print(value % 256) -- 232
```

What have we done here? Let's look 1000 in binary. Since we are working with two-byte values, and each byte is 8 bits, I'll include 16 bits: 0b0000001111101000. (0b is a prefix that is sometimes used to indicate that the following number should be interpreted as binary.) If we split this into the first 8 bits and the second 8 bits, we get: 0b00000011 and 0b11101000. What are these numbers?

```
print(tonumber("00000011",2)) -- 3
print(tonumber("11101000",2)) -- 232
```

So what we have done is split a 2-byte number into two 1-byte numbers. So why does this work? Let's go back to base 10 for a moment. Suppose we have a four-digit number, say 1234, and we want to split it into two two-digit numbers. Well, the quotient 1234 / 100 is 12, and the remainder of that divison is 34. In Lua, that's:

```
print(math.floor(1234 / 100)) -- 12
print(1234 % 100) -- 34
```

Hopefully, you can understand what's happening in base 10 pretty well. (More math here is outside the scope of this answer.) Well, what about 256? 256 is 2 to the power of 8. And there are 8 bits in a byte. In binary, 256 is 0b100000000 -- it's a 1 followed by a bunch of zeros. That means it a similar ability to split binary numbers apart as 100 did in base 10.

Another thing to note here is the concept of endianness. Which should come first, the 3 or the 232? It turns out that different computers (and different protocols) have different answers for this question. I don't know what is correct in your case, you'll have to refer to your documentation. The way you are currently set up is called "big endian" because the big part of the number comes first.

```
--[[What is bit32.rshift actually doing to the string?  and the same is true for the next line with bit32.band.]]
```

Let's look at this whole loop:

```
local out = {}
for i = 1,8 do
    local statusBit = bit32.rshift(res:byte(10), i - 1)
    out[#out + 1] = bit32.band(statusBit, 1)
end
```

And let's pick a concrete number for the sake of example, say, 0b01100111. First let's lookat the band (which is short for "bitwise and"). What does this mean? It means line up the two numbers and see where two 1's occur in the same place.

```
     01100111
band 00000001
-------------
     00000001
```

Notice first that I've put a bunch of 0's in front of the one. Preceeding zeros don't change the value of the number, but I want all 8 bits for both numbers so that I can check each digit (bit) of the first number with each digit of the second number. In each place where there both numbers had a 1 (the top number had a 1 "and" the bottom number had a 1), I put a 1 for the result, otherwise I put 0. That's bitwise and.

When we bitwise and with 0b00000001 as we did here, you should be able to see that we will only get a 1 (0b00000001) or a 0 (0b00000000) as the result. Which we get depends on the last bit of the other number. We have basically separated out the last bit of that number from the rest (which is often called "masking") and stored it in our out array.

Now what about the rshift ("right shift")? To shift right by one, we discard the rightmost digit, and move everything else over one space the the right. (At the left, we usually add a 0 so we still have 8 bits ... as usual, adding a bit in front of a number doesn't change it.)

```
right shift 01100111
            \\\\\\\\
             0110011 ... 1 <-- discarded
```

(Forgive my horrible ASCII art.) So shifting right by 1 changes our 0b01100111 to 0b00110011. (You can also think of this as chopping off the last bit.)

Now what does it mean to shift right be a different number? Well to shift by zero does not change the number. To shift by more than one, we just repeat this operation however many times we are shifting by. (To shift by two, shift by one twice, etc.) (If you prefer to think in terms of chopping, right shift by x is chopping off the last x bits.)

So on the first iteration through the loop, the number will not be shifted, and we will store the rightmost bit.

On the second iteration through the loop, the number will be shifted by 1, and the new rightmost bit will be what was previously the second from the right, so the bitwise and will mask out that bit and we will store it.

On the next iteration, we will shift by 2, so the rightmost bit will be the one that was originally third from the right, so the bitwise and will mask out that bit and store it.

On each iteration, we store the next bit.

Since we are working with a byte, there are only 8 bits, so after 8 iterations through the loop, we will have stored the value of each bit into our table. This is what the table should look like in our example:

```
out = {1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0}
```

Notice that the bits are reversed from how we wrote them 0b01100111 because we started looking from the right side of the binary number, but things are added to the table starting on the left.

In your case, it looks like each bit has a distinct meaning. For example, a 1 in the third bit could mean that sensor1 was on and a 0 in the third bit could mean that sensor1 was off. Eight different pieces of information like this were packed together to make it more efficient to transmit them over some channel. The loop separates them again into a form that is easy for you to use.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer!  I didn't realize how much I did not remember with bit/byte manipulation.  Again, thank you very much for your answer.  Great explanation.