# Lua: Working with the Modbus TCP/IP Protocol

Tags: lua, modbus

This question is based off a previous question I asked concerning a similar topic: [Lua: Working with Bit32 Library to Change States of I/O's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175209/lua-working-with-bit32-library-to-change-states-of-i-os) . I'm trying to use a Lua program that, when a PLC changes the state of a coil at a given address (only two addresses will be used) then it triggers a reaction in another piece of equipment.  I have some code that is basically the exact same as my previous topic.  But this has to do with what this code is *actually* doing and not so much the bit32 library.  Usually I run code I don't in understand in my Linux IDE and slowly make changes until I finally can make sense of it.  But this is producing some weird reactions that I can't make sense of.

Code example:

```
local unitId = 1

local funcCodes = {
    readCoil = 1, 
    readInput = 2,
    readHoldingReg = 3,
    readInputReg = 4,
    writeCoil = 5,
    presetSingleReg = 6,
    writeMultipleCoils = 15,
    presetMultipleReg = 16
}

local function toTwoByte(value) 
    return string.char(value / 255, value % 255) 
end

local coil = 1

local function readCoil(s, coil)
    local req = toTwoByte(0) .. toTwoByte(0) .. toTwoByte(6) .. string.char(unitId, funcCodes.readCoil) .. toTwoByte(coil - 1) .. toTwoByte(1)
    s:write(req) --(s is the address of the I/O module)
    local res = s:read(10)
    return res:byte(10) == 1 -- returns true or false if the 10th bit is ==1 I think???  Please confirm
end
```

The line that sets `local req` is the part I'm truly not making sense of.  Because of my earlier post, I understand fully about the `toTwoByte` function and was quickly refreshed on bits & byte manipulation (truly excellent by the way).  But that particular string is the reason for this confusion.  If I run this in the demo at lua.org I get back an error "lua number has no integer representation".  If I separate it into the following I am given back ascii characters that represent those numbers (which I know `string.char` returns the ascii representation of a given digit).  If I run this in my Linux IDE, it displays a bunch of boxes, each containing four digits; two on top of the other two.  Now it is very hard to distinguish all of the boxes and their content as they are overlapping.

I know that there is a modbus library that I may be able to use.  But I would much rather prefer to understand this as I'm fairly new to programming in general.

Why do I receive different returned results from Windows vs Linux?
What would that string "`local req`" look like when built at this point to the I/O module.  And I don't understand how this `req` variable translates into the proper string that contains all of the information used to read/write to a given coil or register.

If anyone needs better examples or has further questions that I need to answer, please let me know.

Cheers!

ETA:  This is with the Modbus TCP/IP Protocol, not RTU.  Sorry.

Comment: Replace `string.char(value/255, ...` with `string.char(math.floor(value/255), ...`. `req` contains a string of binary values, containing mostly 2-byte integers.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo thank you for your reply.  I understand that it is returning a 2-byte value for each concatenated portion of the `req` variable.  But I don't understand how, when I try to print out the actual `req` variable, I do not see anything?  It would help me a lot more to actually see what it is doing so I know how to exactly address a specific coil or register.  It seems to me that this `req` variable does not match up to the total length required to address them, does it?

Comment: It's a binary string, not plain text. It contains unprintable characters. Write the string to a file and open it with a hex editor.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo great idea.  Thank you Colonel for your input!